# Firebase `error.credential` does not exist when it should for anonymous auth fallback

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

`error.credential` does not exist when using `linkWithPopup` with firebase when getting errors such as `auth/credential-already-in-use` -- which is the whole point of being able to use `error.credential` to fall back and perform a normal login

```
linkWithPopup(auth.currentUser, googleAuthProvider)
        .then((result) => {
            const user = result.user;
            console.log("Anonymous account successfully upgraded", user);
            window.location = redirectUrl;
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error upgrading anonymous account", error);
            console.log(error.credential);
            if (error.credential) {
                signInWithCredential(auth, error.credential)
                    .then((result) => {
                        const user = result.user;
                        console.log("recovered");
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.log("error in google auth recovery", errorMessage);
                    });
            }
        });
```

this code always produces undefined for `error.credential`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, the `error.credential` was deprecated in v9 version of Firebase.
So, you can try to use [credentialFromError](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.oauthprovider.md#oauthprovidercredentialfromerror) method of `OAuthProvider`. And you will get something like this:

```
import {
  OAuthProvider,
} from 'firebase/auth'

linkWithPopup(auth.currentUser, googleAuthProvider).catch(error) {
  const authCredential = await OAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error)
}
```